# Spark Kafka Streaming Reading Data Every X minute

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am running a query in Kafka Cluster using Apache Spark streaming, I want to read the Data for every last 1 minute  and output the same using some logic

For Example : here Time is time in which data is available in Kafka Topic

```
Time =    0 sec      30 sec      1 min     1:15 min    1:30 min   2:00 min
Data =    ("dog",1)  ("dog",2)  ("cat",1)   ("cat",1)  ("cat",3)  ("dog",3)
```

OutPut

```
At time = 1 min
 :   (dog,3) (cat,1)
At time = 2 min
 :   (dog,3) (cat,4)
```

So every 1 minute output the data using some aggression

My Code:

```
 Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaServer )
                .option("subscribe",kafkaTopics)
                .option("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
                .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
                .load();

 Dataset<Row> temp =  df.select( from_avro(col("value")  , schema).as("rows"),
                    col("timestamp"));
                   temp.createOrReplaceTempView("temp");

                  Dataset<Row> table = spark.sql("select rows.* , timestamp from temp");

              Dataset<Row>  result = table
              .groupBy( col("name"), window(col("timestamp"),"1 minutes"))
              .agg(count("*").as("Total"));
```

Printing it on Console :

```
 StreamingQuery ds = result
                        .writeStream()
                        .queryName("Test query")
                        .outputMode("complete")
                        .format("console")
                        .option("truncate", "false")
                        .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
                        .start();
```

But it's not writing the correct result i.e after every 1 minute it should process the last 1 minute data and output the result ?

Comment: The reading is continuous, but if you want to bucket the events, have you looked at the windowing functions? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time

Comment: @OneCricketeer 
I have used the ` sliding window function` is my code, via `tumbling window` which is present in my code I can't do ? Is this correct

Comment: I have to  used the `sliding window function` is my code ? 
 I can't edit my previous comment

Comment: Well, what output is your code actually printing? Do the examples in the documentation diagrams make sense?